# mysql - get closest value to correct value return zero to many depending on result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My site allows users to guess the result of a sports match. At the end of the match the guesses should be compared to the actual result. The winner(s) are the members with the closest correct guess

Im looking for a way to return all members who guessed the correct result and score difference IF NO (zero) member guessed correctly return members who guessed **closest** to the correct result

[See MYSQL FIDLE EXAMPLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11cf/4)

I modified the script to change fixed values taking variables as you can see below

```
if(isset($_POST['resultBtn'])){
    foreach($_POST['winner'] as $id =>$winner){
        $winScore = $_POST['score'][$id];
        :
        :


$sql="SELECT p.*
        FROM Multiple_Picks p
        WHERE p.event_id='$matchId' AND 
        p.pick='$winner' AND
        abs(p.score-'$winScore') = (SELECT min(abs(p2.score-1))
                        FROM Multiple_Picks p2
                        Where p2.pick=p.pick AND
                        p2.event_id = p.event_id)";
```

My problem is if I run this script on the following table:

[image]

NOTHING gets displayed even if I put result exactly correct:

My variable values are correct in the sql statment so that is not the problem

Any help will be welcomed...

**IMPORTANT THE USER WHO SELECTED CLOSEST CORRECT RESULTS, FOR ALL GAME, DURING THE ROUND IS THE WINNER**

example: if user A won 4 of the picks and user B won 5 of the picks then user B is the winner of the round

Comment: Why dont you just generate difference b/w user's guess and result in descending order?

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo Because if NO member did not pick EXACTLY the correct score I need to get the member who picked CLOSEST to correct score

Comment: If the data type of your columns is `int`, you do not need to put `''` around the PHP variables.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee should every `round_game_nr` be compared on its own, so that there will be minimum 8 rows (1 user closest match) in the output and maximum 16 (2 users exact closest match) in your scenario (given the data sample)? Why should anybody be selected, when nobody guessed the right winner?

Comment: Your example code is trying to select the closest picks for one game, but then you say "IMPORTANT THE USER WHO SELECTED CLOSEST CORRECT RESULTS, FOR ALL GAME, DURING THE ROUND IS THE WINNER".  Are you actually asking for code that works out the winner of the round? If so, please create a fiddle with example data with picks for all games for a number of players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I call a "Best" pick any pick that has chosen the correct winner for a particular match, and has the closest score to the actual match score.

These scripts also respect the different "rounds" in the competition, since that is an important complication.

This answer comes in two parts: first a query that is similar to the one in the question that returns all the "Best" picks for a particular match.  To make it easier to run in SQL Fiddle, I have used MySQL variables instead of PHP variables.

Schema with test data:

```sql
create table Multiple_Picks (
  pick_id int,
  member_nr int,
  event_id int,
  pick varchar(100),
  score int
  );

insert into Multiple_Picks 
values
(11,100,1,'Crusaders',15),
(12,100,2,'Waratahs',10),
(13,100,3,'Chiefs',4),

(21,200,1,'Crusaders',15),
(22,200,2,'Waratahs',10),
(23,200,3,'Lions',4),

(31,300,1,'Crusaders',15),
(32,300,2,'Waratahs',12),
(33,300,3,'Lions',6),

(41,100,4,'Crusaders',20),
(42,100,5,'Waratahs',20),
(43,100,6,'Lions',20)
;
```

Queries to show all picks and then best picks for a particular match:

```sql
set @matchId = 2;
set @winner = 'Waratahs';
set @winScore = 8;

-- Show all picks for a particular match
select * from Multiple_Picks
where event_id = @matchId;

-- Show best picks for a particular match
select p.*
from Multiple_Picks p
where p.event_id = @matchId
and p.pick = @winner
and abs(p.score - @winScore) = 
  (select min(abs(other.score - @winScore)) 
   from Multiple_Picks other
   where other.event_id = @matchId
   and other.pick = @winner
  )
;
```

[SQL Fiddle to show picks for particular match](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17d73/1)

```sql
-- Show all picks for a particular match
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+
| pick_id | member_nr | event_id |   pick   | score |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+
|      12 |       100 |        2 | Waratahs |    10 |
|      22 |       200 |        2 | Waratahs |    10 |
|      32 |       300 |        2 | Waratahs |    12 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+

-- Show best picks for a particular match
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+
| pick_id | member_nr | event_id |   pick   | score |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+
|      12 |       100 |        2 | Waratahs |    10 |
|      22 |       200 |        2 | Waratahs |    10 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Now we need to work towards finding the winner of each round of the competition.

First we have extra test data that contains the actual scores for Matches in rounds 1 and 2.

```sql
create table Matches (
  event_id int,
  winner varchar(100),
  score int,
  round int
  );

insert into Matches 
values
(1,'Crusaders',10,1),
(2,'Waratahs',11,1),
(3,'Lions',4,1),

(4,'Crusaders',20,2),
(5,'Waratahs',20,2),
(6,'Chiefs',20,2)
;
```

Now select the best picks for all Matches.  The subselect (aliased as m) calculates best_diff for each match as the minimum difference between the actual score and every guessed score.  This subselect is then joined to every pick so that only "Best" picks are returned.

```sql
-- Show all best picks for all Matches
select p.*, m.round
from Multiple_Picks p
join (
  select m2.event_id, m2.winner, m2.score, m2.round, 
         min(abs(m2.score-p2.score)) as best_diff
  from Matches m2
  join Multiple_Picks p2
  on p2.event_id = m2.event_id and p2.pick = m2.winner
  group by m2.event_id, m2.winner, m2.score, m2.round
) as m
on p.event_id = m.event_id and p.pick = m.winner 
   and abs(m.score - p.score) = m.best_diff
order by m.round, p.event_id
;
```

It is then easy to get a count of Best picks for each player for each round by just grouping the previous query by member_nr and round:

```sql
-- Show a count of best picks for each player for each round
select p.member_nr, m.round, count(*) as best_count
from Multiple_Picks p
join (
  select m2.event_id, m2.winner, m2.score, m2.round, 
         min(abs(m2.score-p2.score)) as best_diff
  from Matches m2
  join Multiple_Picks p2
  on p2.event_id = m2.event_id and p2.pick = m2.winner
  group by m2.event_id, m2.winner, m2.score, m2.round
) as m
on p.event_id = m.event_id and p.pick = m.winner 
   and abs(m.score - p.score) = m.best_diff
group by p.member_nr, m.round
order by m.round, count(*) desc
;
```

[SQL Fiddle for all best picks and counts for all matches](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/518c4/2)

```sql
-- Show all best picks for all Matches
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| pick_id | member_nr | event_id |   pick    | score | round |
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
|      31 |       300 |        1 | Crusaders |    15 |     1 |
|      21 |       200 |        1 | Crusaders |    15 |     1 |
|      11 |       100 |        1 | Crusaders |    15 |     1 |
|      12 |       100 |        2 | Waratahs  |    10 |     1 |
|      32 |       300 |        2 | Waratahs  |    12 |     1 |
|      22 |       200 |        2 | Waratahs  |    10 |     1 |
|      23 |       200 |        3 | Lions     |     4 |     1 |
|      41 |       100 |        4 | Crusaders |    20 |     2 |
|      42 |       100 |        5 | Waratahs  |    20 |     2 |
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+

-- Show a count of best picks for each player for each round
+-----------+-------+------------+
| member_nr | round | best_count |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       200 |     1 |          3 |
|       300 |     1 |          2 |
|       100 |     1 |          2 |
|       100 |     2 |          2 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

The final stage is to select only those players for each round who have the highest number of Best picks.  I tried modifying the above queries, but the nesting becomes two confusing, so my solution was to create a few logical views so that the final query can be more easily understood.  The views basically encapsulate the logic of the queries I have explained above:

```sql
create view MatchesWithBestDiff as
select m.event_id, m.winner, m.score, m.round, 
       min(abs(m.score-p.score)) as best_diff
from Matches m 
join Multiple_Picks p
on p.event_id = m.event_id and p.pick = m.winner
group by m.event_id, m.winner, m.score, m.round
;

create view BestPicks as
select p.*, m.round
from Multiple_Picks p
join MatchesWithBestDiff m
on p.event_id = m.event_id and p.pick = m.winner 
   and abs(m.score - p.score) = m.best_diff
;

create view BestPickCount as
select member_nr, round, count(*) as best_count
from BestPicks
group by member_nr, round
;
```

So that the query that shows the winners of each round is simply:

```sql
-- Show the players with the highest number of Best Picks for each round
select *
from BestPickCount p
where best_count = 
(
    select max(other.best_count)
    from BestPickCount other
    where other.round = p.round
)
order by round
;
```

[SQL Fiddle for players with most Best picks for each round](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/788049/1)

```sql
-- Show the players with the highest number of Best Picks for each round
+-----------+-------+------------+
| member_nr | round | best_count |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       200 |     1 |          3 |
|       100 |     2 |          2 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

This whole investigation has reminded me how tricky it can be to get SQL to do much manipulation where records need to be selected depending on maximums and sums.  Some of these types of queries can be much easier with window functions (the OVER and PARTITION BY clauses), but they are not available in MySQL.

While designing the above queries, I found a few interesting restrictions:
MySQL does not allow joins to subqueries in views definitions.
ANSI SQL does not allow an aggregate in a subquery to reference both a column from the inner query and a column from the outer query.  MySQL seems to sometimes allow this, but I couldn't find clear guidance as to when it is allowed, so I chose to code the above queries to avoid this "feature".

Comment: Thats some serious SQL happening there - you obviously know your stuff, i never would have thought about such an approach, thank you very much for taking the time to write all that out for me, very much appreciated.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee It grabbed my attention and I couldn't let go. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi JOhn Just one very stupid question if you dont mind - Im about to implement this code and will let you know how it went.I take it I will have to have a results table where I set the winner and score parameters from, I will then need to loop over each match  in the round one by one....correct?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I don't know the UI you expect to provide, but I expect your process to be something like: The players have a web interface where they enter picks into the Multiple_Picks table.  Then you as the application owner have an interface where you can enter the actual match results into the Matches table.  Then your app can query the views (BestPickCount in particular) to work out which player made the highest number of Best picks in a round.  You need to enter the info for every match into the Matches table, but there is no other looping required to work out which player has won.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Maybe I understand the confusion. If all you want is the winner of the whole round then you can ignore the query I called "Show best picks for a particular match". Instead just use the BestPickCount view and the last query to get the round winner/s. No looping required.

Comment: Thank you so much mate your comment`The players have a web interface where they enter picks into the Multiple_Picks table. I have an interface where I can enter the actual match results into the Matches table. Then your app can query the views (BestPickCount in particular) to work out which player made the highest number of Best picks in a round. You need to enter the info for every match into the Matches table, but there is no other looping required to work out which player has won.` HOWEVER I WOULD ALSO LIKE TO DISPLAY THE WINNER FOR EACH MATCH SO WILL MAKE USE OF YOUR WHOLE SOLUTION

Comment: IM GETTING THERE MATE THANKS AGAIN - WILL LET YOU KNOW SHORTLY

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Any closer? Close enough to accept an answer? ;-)

Comment: Done just gave you 100rep - you deserved it, will you mind if i contact you in the future if i have a few more questions?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Thank you. And absolutely I'm happy to help with more questions.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Were you able to implement any of this?  I would be particularly interested if you had any comments about its performance.  I do not know how these queries will scale to the amount of data that you expect to have in these tables.

Comment: sorry for late reply...I'm actually still struggling to get this implemented I am working on a number of tweaks and will give you an update shortly

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want just

```
SELECT p.*, abs(p.score-'$winScore') as diff
        FROM Multiple_Picks p
        WHERE p.event_id='$matchId' AND p.pick='$winner'
        ORDER BY diff ASC 
        LIMIT 1
```

This will return the closest member for the event. Remove the `LIMIT` if you need a few of them.

Also, never put your parameters directly into the SQL query, even trusted ones (not your case) and even if you're sure they will always be integer or non-string type. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

> scenario 1: NO USERS SELECTED THE CORRECT TEAM

I believe that result in this situation should be empty result because everyone has made a mistake.

> SCORE RETURN MEMBERS WHO SELECTED THE CLOSEST TO CORRECT SCORE AND
>   RESULT

It seems to be already working in your code example except one mistake in select.

```
 abs(p.score-'$winScore') = (SELECT min(abs(p2.score-1))
```

Instead of constant `1` (one) it should be variable `'$winScore'`

and to control the number of users you get, you may limit your results so you will get something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT p.*
        FROM Multiple_Picks p
        WHERE p.event_id='$matchId' AND 
        p.pick='$winner' AND
        abs(p.score-'$winScore') = (SELECT min(abs(p2.score-'$winner'))
                        FROM Multiple_Picks p2
                        Where p2.pick=p.pick AND
                        p2.event_id = p.event_id)
order by p.id limit '$numberOfMembers'";
```

> SCENARIO 2: SCENARIO 2: MULTIPLE USERS SELECTED CORRECT TEAM BUT
>   SCORES ARE  DIFFERENT RETURN USER(S) WHO GUESSED CLOSEST TO CORRECT
>   SCORE

Same as in the previous question.

> SCENARIO 3: MULTIPLE USERS SELECTED CORRECT TEAM AND SCORE RETURN  ALL
>   USERS WHO SELECTED CORRECT TEAM AND SCORE

You can achieve this using same query just replace the LIMIT with 'rank' function, and also if you will get several closest scores, but you have to limit their number according to their voting order by id, for this purpose I suggest sorting.
So final query will be:

```
$sql="select * from (SELECT p.*, 
         abs(p.score-'$winScore') scr_diff,
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 rank
        FROM Multiple_Picks p,
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) rank_gen
        WHERE p.event_id='$matchId' AND 
        p.pick='$winner' AND
        abs(p.score-'$winScore') = (SELECT min(abs(p2.score-'$winner'))
                        FROM Multiple_Picks p2
                        Where p2.pick=p.pick AND
                        p2.event_id = p.event_id)
order by p.id
  ) sq
 where sq.scr_diff = 0
    or sq.rank < '$numberOfMembers'";
```

[Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d11cf/84)

Answer (score 1):

**Best guesser for one match**

First find the member(s) who picked the winner and had the closest score guess:

```
SELECT  p.*
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  MIN(ABS(score-'$winScore')) AS closest
            FROM  Multiple_Picks
            WHERE  event_id = '$matchId'
              AND  pick='$winner' 
      ) AS c
    JOIN  Multiple_Picks p
    WHERE  p.event_id = '$matchId'
      AND  p.pick = '$winner'
      AND  ABS(score-'$winScore') = c.closest
```

If that return no results, then what should happen?  (It would be because no one picked the winner for a particular event.)

But, I think your question is much more complex.  However, the above gives a mapping from (event_id, pick) -> list-of-members who "won".  Starting over...

**Missing info**

There is a mystery -- Where do the event results come from?  I will assume this table is already populated:

```
CREATE TABLE Win (
    event_id ...,   -- which game
    winnner ...,    -- who won
    score ...       -- by what score
)
```

**Best guesser overall**

So, create a table of BestGuessers(event_id, member).  The details of "all game" and "round" are a bit vague.  So I will carry this at least one step further.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE BestGuessers(
    event_id ...,
    member_nr ...   -- who guessed the best for that event
)
SELECT  p.event_id, p.member_nr
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  w.event_id, w.winner, MIN(ABS(mp.score-w.score)) AS closest
            FROM  Multiple_Picks AS mp
            JOIN  Win AS w ON mp.event_id = w.event_id
              AND  mp.pick = w.winner
            GROUP BY  w.event_id, w.winner 
      ) AS c
    JOIN  Multiple_Picks p
         ON  p.event_id = c.event_id
        AND  p.pick = c.pick
        AND  p.score = c.closest
```

Now, from that, you can pick the best guesser(s).

```
SELECT  y.member_nr
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS ct
            FROM  BestGuessers
            GROUP BY  member_nr
            ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
            LIMIT  1 
      ) AS x   -- the max number of correct guesses
    STRAIGHT_JOIN  
      ( SELECT  member_nr, COUNT(*) AS ct
            FROM  BestGuessers
            GROUP BY  member_nr
      ) AS y   -- the users who guessed correctly that many times
     USING (ct);
```

All this is pretty complex; I may have some typos, even logic errors.  But maybe I came close.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an additional table to store the actual results would help here.
E.g let's say this is in a table called `results` with sample values as follows:

```
event_id  winner     result
1         Crusaders  16
2         Waratahs   15
3         Chiefs      4
4         Crusaders  17
5         Reds       12
0         Rebels     14
7         Cheetahs   15
8         Crusaders  14
```

This can then be `JOIN`ed on each row and results compared as follows:

```
SELECT p.*
     , CASE WHEN ABS(p.score - r.result)
                 - CASE WHEN p.pick = r.winner THEN 999999 ELSE 0 END
                 = (SELECT MIN(ABS(p2.score - r2.result)
                               - CASE WHEN p2.pick = r2.winner THEN 999999 ELSE 0 END)
                    FROM picks p2
                    JOIN results r2
                    ON p2.event_id = r2.event_id
                    WHERE p2.event_id = p.event_id)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS win
FROM picks p
JOIN results r
ON p.event_id = r.event_id;
```

**Explanation**

The rightmost `win` column is 1 if the member is calculated to have won or drawn the event, otherwise it is 0. The method used is similar to the one in your post, with the main difference being the team and score are combined. The main thing to be explained here is the 999999, which is subtracted when a correct team is picked - so this can be sure to eclipse the score difference. (Of course, an even bigger value could be picked if needed).

**Demo**

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed3f9/6)

Comment: Thank you so much steve Im going to try and implement it today and see if it works, I will get back to you shortly